# How do I avoid having to use isset() in Laravel Blade templates?

Tags: laravel-blade

I've got a Blade file like this:

```
<a href="{{ $url }}" class="{{ $wrapperClass }}">
  <p class="{{ $paraClass }}">{{ $title }}</p>
</a>
```

And call it like this:

```
<x-mycomponent
  url="{{ $book->url }}"
  title={{ $book->title }}
  wrapper-class=""
  para-class = ""
/>
```

Works great, but whenever I want to add a variable to the component, I need to add this to each file where I call this component.

How can I write it without having to specify all variables and without having to use `isset()` or `{{  $myvar ?? '' }}` in Blade? like this:

```
<x-mycomponent
  url="{{ $book->url }}"
  title={{ $book->title }}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign default values for your properties like the below's peace of code:

```
@props([
    "product" => null
])

<a href="#">{{ $product }}</a>
```

and then, you can call your component in both these ways:

```
<x-mycomponent />
<x-mycomponent product="$product" />
```

Note: `@props` is a Blade directive that allows you to pass data from a parent component to a child component.